# Using Zend Mail Pop3 as a module

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, module

I would like to use the Mail module of Zend Framework. I have extracted all the Zend lib in my project lib folder.

So how can I load the Mail module for using this module: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.0/en/zend.mail.read.html?

I have tried this:

```
include("lib/Zend/Loader.php");
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Mail');

$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3(array('host'     => 'xxxxx',
                                         'user'     => 'xxxxx',
                                         'password' => 'xxxxx'));
```

My project structure is this:

```
-project->lib->Zend->All the Zend lib files

-projects/index.php
```

For example:

```
 Warning: require_once(Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Do I really have to modify all the `require_once` manually?

But I have returned errors about include path in others module files.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @takeshin what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

See the autoloader reference:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.autoloading.usage.html

and php's `__autoload` function if you want to write custom autoloader.

You may also add the paths with the libraries to the `include_path` (see `set_include_path`/`get_include_path`)

e.g.

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    'path/to/zend/lib/',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader_Autoloader' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\zendmail\index.php on line 4

Comment: line 4 ==> Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();